# Extracting bigger raster with smaller raster in way that bigger raster has NoData where smaller raster cells are?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, extract

I want to extract the raster cells from a big raster with the raster cells from a smaller raster which is overlapping with the bigger raster. Unfortunately, I cannot find a tool for that in ArcMap 10.3.1, but is there a way to do it? I do not want to subtract the values, but there should be noData in the new bigger raster where the bigger raster is overlapping with the smaller raster, like a hole in the bigger raster with the extent of the smaller one.

[image]

Comment: Con(is null(small),big)  in raster calculator.

Answer (score 1):

Use a conditional statement in the raster calculator.

See the ArcGIS documentation on:

- [Conditional evaluation with Con](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/conditional-evaluation-with-con.htm); and
- [Raster Calculator](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/raster-calculator.htm).

**EDIT**
You can set the output in the area of the smaller raster to something like 9999 and then use the setNull tool, or reclassify to turn it to NoData.  Another simple alternative, if the 'smaller' raster has the same extent as the bigger one, is to use the reclassify tool to make the black area (persumably currently set to a value of 0) to NoData and the NoData areas to 1.  Then simple multiply the result of that operation with 'bigger'.

Comment: Thank you. This is the solution at the moment:
`Con(IsNull("smaller"),"bigger","bigger" == "smaller") 
I reclassified the smaller raster to raster value 0 before running the raster calculator but I could not find a solution to get noData for the smaller raster extension in the bigger raster. Does someone have an advice?

Comment: Okay, I really need to put the values from the smaller raster into noData. Having them only set to 0 is not enough because there are also other raster cells with the value 0 and I need them for my statistic. It would be wonderful if someone can support me with the raster calculator expression. Thanks!

Comment: The simplest way is to use a second step - see my edits.

Comment: I am sorry for asking again, I just didn't get the point how to “set the output in the area of the smaller raster to something like 9999” with the combination of the bigger raster. Sorry, but I haven’t used the tool “CON” before…. Thank you so much

Comment: Try: Con(smaller = 0, NoData, bigger).  assuming that the black area of smaller is zero (based on your comments).  I don't have ArcGIS to hand and its been a while so I can't remember if it will take the NoData entry.  If that fails then do it in two steps as described above using Con(smaller = 0, -99999, bigger).  Then reclassify the result to set -99999 to NoData.  To summarize, in the con statement you can either reference a raster to give the output value or you can specify a number for the true or false values in the con statement.

Comment: Okay it is working with 9999 as raster value for the smaller raster by using Con(IsNull("smaller"),"bigger", "smaller"), the tool int and than ‘extract by attributes’. Thank you